# Format DateTime for JQuery in MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm passing into my view some JSON data that includes many things, including a DateTime. I'm currently encoding it in the Controller as the ISO format, so I am getting `2017-10-13T23:21:00` as my date, however I'm not sure how to bring it to a more friendly `10/13/17 11:21pm`.

Currently it is being rendered in the view as part of a javascript script. The specific part is:

```
var template = "<tr><td>${DateTime}</td><td>${OtherStuff}</td></tr>"
```

I tried

```
var dt = new Date("${DateTime}")
var template = "<tr><td>" + dt + "</td><td>${OtherStuff}</td></tr>"
```

Without success (instead of the expected output I received a "Invalid Date"). The error I received leads me to think I'm headed down the right path, just off ever so slightly.

---

Add some additonal code in case it helps

This is all part of

```
$(function () {
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var renderTable = function (success, error) {
        var dt = new Date("${DateTime}");
        var template = "<tr><td>" + dt + "</td><td>${OtherStuff}</td></tr>"

        if (success) {
            $("#table tbody").empty();
                $($.ig.tmpl(template, ds.dataView())).appendTo("#table tbody");
            } else {
                alert(error);
            }
        }

        //This code creates an $.ig.DataSource from JSON data
        var ds = new $.ig.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            dataSource: data,
            callback: renderTable
        });

        // Binds to the underlying data
        ds.dataBind();
    });
```

I believe I see the issue now, template is just that, a template, so I can't format the placeholder variable that will later be filled. But how do I do that?

Comment: libraries like moment.js are helpful for dealing with dates and cut down a lot of manual coding

Comment: Try jQuery date format https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat I think "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm" is am/pm format

Comment: Both of those look neat and handy, but I haven't the foggiest on how to use them in context of what I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call toLocaleString() method on your date object to make it language friendly.

```
var defaultDate = new Date("2017-10-13T23:21:00"); // Fri Oct 13 2017 23:21:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
var languageFriendlyDate = defaultDate.toLocaleString(); // 10/13/2017, 11:21:00 PM
```

You can also pass the specific locale as an argument of the toLocaleString() method.

```
// US English uses month-day-year order and 12-hour time with AM/PM
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'));
// → "12/19/2012, 7:00:00 PM"
```

For more details check:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString